# Monitoring HTTP Response/Request size from ASP.NET on Linux server

Tags: asp.net, linux, server

We have an ASP.NET Core API running on a linux machine. It seems to be sending and receiving larger and larger amounts of data that is killing our bandwidth quota. Is there a linux program or an ASP.NET extension that can help us find out if the server is doing HTTP requests/responses with huge payloads or perhaps doing one type of HTTP request/response a few billion times a second?